# how do i remove a div and load new div in its place?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i need to click a button and remove a div and then load a new div in its place. Both div's contain a bit of html and a script.

using the below remove/show method, div1 loads perfectly but after button clicked div2 replaces div1 but only the html from div2 is loaded. The div2 script is for some reason not loaded.

```
<div id="div1">div1 contents</div>
<div id="div2" style="display: none">div2 contents</div>
<button id="button">Button</button>

$('#button').on('click', function() {
    $('#div1').remove();
    $('#div2').show();
});
```

Is there a way to remove div1 and then load the new div2 fresh in its place rather than just unhide div2?

Comment: you probably want to call that script methods when you show div2

Comment: You can try `replaceWith()`

Comment: And where exactly is the problem, as in position of div 2?

Comment: have you given the scripts in the external file or inside the tag?

Comment: Where is div2 script?

Comment: Have you ever try to use ajax ?

Comment: div2 script is inside div2

Comment: i wouldn't know where to start with ajax :-/

Comment: here is a link to where i am trying to achieve this: http://v80.undergroundsoundz.com/usz-radio i'm trying to replace 1 video player if another

Comment: Is it a requisite to have the script inside the div, and not inside the click() event? Because probably javascript in div2 is triggering on page load rather than on show.

Comment: the script inside the div's are quite big as they are the config to a video player so guessing it was best to put inside the div?

Comment: can anyone suggest an ajax solution? would this be the best way to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var $origin = $('#div1'),
    replacementSrc = '/path/to/div2.html',
    replacementScriptsSrc = '/path/to/div2.js';

$('#button').on('click', function () {
    $.load(replacementSrc, function (html) {
        $origin.replaceWith(html);
        $.getScript(replacementScriptsSrc/*, function () { doSomething(); }*/);
    });
});
```

Comment: this didn't replace it at all for some reason

Comment: Sorry I posted the first solution by mistake

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
$('#button').on('click', function() {
    $('#div1').html('div 2 contents');
});
```

In this example you would not need the  line from your example above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
      $('#button').on('click', function() {
            $('#div1').html($('#div2').html());
      });
});
```

The issue was with your script. Actually the script was loaded into `div1` but then script throw this error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jwplayer is not defined
```

This will exit.So as a result no script is loading.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/carunchandran/xu4UF/)

Comment: div2 contents do not appear on this example

Comment: did you check demo link ?

Comment: yes but it doesn't replace the content, div1 content disappears and div2 content does not appear in its place

Comment: Check this http://screencast.com/t/YZTQVctkeKCW. I am able to see the content changed. are you doing something different? or did you expect something else ?

Comment: ok sorry, the script works but still doesn't load the script from div2. see here: http://v80.undergroundsoundz.com/test-page

Comment: are you using jquery ?

Comment: check the answer i had updated. The issue was with your script . you are calling before initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Is it something like this you are working with!!

```
div{
height:100px;
width:100px;
margin:10px;
}

.b{
background:green;
}

.c{
display:none;
background:blue;
}
```

the `HTML`

```
<div class="b">
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#button').click(function(){
$('.c').show();
$('.b').remove();
})  
});

</script>
</div>
<div class="c">
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.c').click(function(){
$(this).css('background','red');
})
});
</script>
</div>
<input type="button" id="button">
```

This is working for me.

Comment: no see here... http://v80.undergroundsoundz.com/usz-radio trying to replace 1 video player with another